# Generate Quasi-Random Samples from Distribution Object

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I've got several distribution objects in Matlab like this one:

```
% gravity [m/s2]
Uncer.Param.gravity.LB = 9.801;
Uncer.Param.gravity.UB = 9.867;
Uncer.Param.gravity.pd = makedist('Uniform','Lower',Uncer.Param.gravity.LB, 'Upper', Uncer.Param.gravity.UB);
Uncer.Param.gravity.value=0;
```

I know I can generate a random sample with the [random](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.truncatabledistribution.random.html)-function, but I want to generate a sample made of quasi-random-numbers (Sobol).

I get a matrix filled with these quasi-random-numbers like this:

```
set = net(sobolset(countParameter*2, 'Skip',1), countSimulation);
```

And I know furthermore, that I can interpolate the distribution values with the function [interp1](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) and the corresponding [CDF](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.truncatabledistribution.cdf.html).

The problem is that my matrix-dimensions are round about 1000x20 and the interpolation would cost a ton ammount of time.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The search has come to an end and was way to simple: [icdf](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.truncatabledistribution.icdf.html)